# Windows Server 2022 Unresponsive UI

Tags: ssd, performance, windows-server

Recently commissioned a new server running Windows Server 2022 with pretty beefy specs (2x Intel Xeon Gold 5320 CPU @ 2.20GHz, 256GB RAM, O/S on 1TB RAID 1 SSD, 24x4TB SSD for database, etc).

It is very slow from a UI-responsiveness perspective - task manager/resource monitor take 6-7 seconds to open and the mouse cursor frequently 'beach balls'. The status of interactive applications often change to 'not responding'.

There doesn't appear to be any resource constraints (CPU, memory, disk all look fine in task manager)

I've set the Performance Options to Adjust For Best Performance of 'Programs' (default was Background ServIces). I've tried restarting.

Windows is activated and all available Windows updates have been applied.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am at my wits end...

[image: Passmark Rating]

2021-11-19 Update - I've been poking around with sysinternals tools and this doesn't look normal:

[image]

I checked another server that is running smooth like butter and Context Switch Delta is < 200,000. Now to try and figure out what's going on...

2021-11-26 Update

Using Windows Performance Analyzer, it appears as though NDIS.sys and tcpip.sys are causing the excessive interrupts. I tried updating to the latest version of the network drivers that I could find but it didn't have an effect:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything suspicious shown in Event Viewer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't see anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the data SSD’s leaving just the boot ones?

Comment: @Shea Are the motherboard manufacturer's drivers installed? Does Device Manager show any problems?

Comment: @JamesP I haven't tried that (I'm physically 1/2 way across the continent from the server so any requests like that would have to be performed by the customer who is already a bit annoyed with us given the expensive server they bought is acting like a late-90's PC without UltraDMA enabled...)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Device manager looks okay to me, but I'm also not an expert. I've added screenshots to the post. It also seems like the problem might be limited to one Windows session - I installed VNC which, when I connected, took me into a different session from which I was experiencing the issues and it seems responsive...

Comment: @Shea You added that the context switch delta seems high: have you seen [How to tell if context switching is too high](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2eb8e224-59c4-4da2-867d-a61a9a7d23bb/how-to-tell-if-context-switching-is-too-high?forum=winservergen)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, thanks, I had stumbled across that in my investigation. I believe 2 million+ is too high. We have a Windows 2012 system with the same software under similar load that is very responsive and it has < 200,000 interrupts per second. I just added a screenshot from Windows Performance Analyzer...

Comment: @Shea 1) Is the machine using on-board Ethernet or a card? 2) I found [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fd06d5c1-2281-4d64-8344-240abb99cd3f/ndissys-consuming-20-of-cpu-going-nuts-trying-to-resolve-this-problem?forum=w7itprohardware) where a user found that CPU overheating made it look like ndis.sys was guilty.

Comment: @AndrewMorton 1) It has (and is using 6 ports from) 3x Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X710-T4L, 4x 10Gb cards, so 12 10GB ports total. 2) Interesting thread, not sure if that explains our situation given the CPU appears consistently low (we have disabled any sort of CPU throttling in both the BIOS and via Power Management in Windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a satisfying resolution and might not be possible for some people, but the problem was solved in our case by installing Windows 10. The number of interrupts is 1/20th of what we were seeing under Windows Server 2022.